# Admob site/app url?

Tags: android, url, admob

I could not find anywhere information: why do I need to fill the Android Package URL of Site/Apps in Admob?
What is it good for, used for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this tip (shown in the attached image), when, say, adding your app to your AdMob account.

[image]

This is the quote from the same pop-up.

> AdMob recommends using the following URL format for linking to an App
>   in the Android Market:
>
> market://details?id=
>
> We have found that routing users to the "Details" page of an app has
>   the best results for driving app downloads. The Android Market will
>   always display the "Details" page for the latest version of the
>   application.
>
> If you are linking to an Android App that is not in the Android
>   Market, you may use http://

This is a helpful feature that comes into play when you choose to / want to *advertise your own app* on the AdMob *"network"*. When other applications show advertisements and your ad for your app is shown, and users click on it, they will be redirected to your app's details page on the Google Play store.

This is, for a better part, optional. And if you won't be running your own ad campaign to promote your app, this is pretty much a non issue.

You will also find a little description (although not too helpful) in this document title [Register your app](http://support.google.com/admob/answer/1307244?hl=en&ref_topic=1307236)

Comment: Thank you. So this means, if I do not advertise my own app, it can remain empty.

Comment: @user1525388: Yup. You can leave it empty. I have done so when I was testing apps prior to their release and never faced any issues with that.